# global variable in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am a novice Python/Tkinter user and not clear for me how to pass widget content.
I supposed usrtext is a global variable - but it prints an empty string. However, Text has real content.
What is the way to pass correctly?

```
class App(object):

    def __init__(self, root):
        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.grid()
        usrtext = Text(bg = "light yellow", fg = "black",relief=SUNKEN)
        usrtext.grid(row=0, columnspan=16, rowspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=5, pady=5)
...
...
def do_it():
    print usrtext       // I'd like to see usrtext _here_
...
...
root = Tk()
root.title("My First Attempt")
usrtext=StringVar()
usrtext=""
...
...
butt1 = Button(root, text='Do it', height=1, width=10, relief=RAISED, command=do_it)
butt1.grid(row=4, column=14)

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get text from `Text` you use

- `get(start,end)` to get text from Text
- `insert(position, text)` to add text to Text

`usrtext.insert(END, "Hello World")`

`print usrtext.get(1.0, END)`

see more: [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

By the way: you use `usrtext` to two elements

```
usrtext=StringVar()
usrtext=Text()
```

so in one moment usrtext is `StringVar` in other `Text` - I think it is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting everything inside your application class, then you can reference the widgets via self. You've got the same variable name in multiple places but they don't refer to the same thing.

```
import Tkinter


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.parent = master

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(self)

        self.user_text = Tkinter.Text(frame, relief=Tkinter.SOLID, borderwidth=2)
        self.user_text.grid(
            row=0,
            columnspan=16,
            rowspan=2,
            sticky=Tkinter.W+Tkinter.E+Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S,
            padx=5,
            pady=5)

        self.butt1 = Tkinter.Button(frame, text='Do it!', command=self.do_it)
        self.butt1.grid(row=2, columnspan=16)

        frame.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, side=Tkinter.BOTTOM)
        self.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

    def do_it(self):
        user_text_string = self.user_text.get(1.0, Tkinter.END)
        print user_text_string


def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I had the same when I answered for PyGame questions. Now I'm tired of this.